# Website Not Working After Google Shut It Down and Restarted

Tags: wordpress, google-cloud-platform, debian, apache2

I installed a Wordpress blog on Google Cloud through their MarketPlace over a year ago. It was free/covered by Google's $300 credit. A month ago I had about $100 credit left but didn't realize the credit was only good for one year and then they would charge. Unfortunately, I had a different credit card on file that was not valid at the time they started charging and because I didn't check my website for a few weeks, I came back and found it was down. When I corrected the billing issue I saw I had to restart the Virtual Machine. I saw that the SSD disk still had had installed "bitnami-wordpress-5-4-1-0-linux-debian-9-x86-6" and when I go to the website apmwellness.com it shows the "Apache2 Debian Default Page" and my static IP address is still saved. I tried to access the website directly through the static IP "34.75.174.18" and still get the same Apache2 page. A Google support person (from sales, not tech) mentioned that when they shut down they delete storage, but how come the SSD still shows bitname wordpress? Do I need to install Wordpress over again and create the website from the backup I fortunately saved or is their a way to recover it without doing that? I'm still waiting for their tech team to get back to me. Thanks!

Comment: 1) Edit your question and include the Apache configuration. 2) SSH into the instance and see if your files are still there.

Comment: Probably the question is offtopic (not about programming: programming is a small subset of all "computer things"). BTW you are assuming too much (which it bad on finding problems). Start from low level, and check what do you have, what is it working correct, and so continue to higher level, until you find where you have the problem. Then you may ask a more targeted question (and possibly not in this website)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.